# How to declare a global variable to be used on a C# expression

Tags: c#, global-variables, scope, declaration

I´m doing this :

```
protected void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){

var myQuery = from tab1 in Table
              where myConditions
              select tab1 ;
```

After that, I´m filtering with user selected choices :

```
myQuery.Where(x => x.someField == someChoice);
```

It´s working fine. But I would like to declare the "myQuery" with global escope.

How should I do that ? I´m trying to put the line below inside the class and outside the method, but I don´t know what type should I use :

```
private someTypeThatIdontKnow myQuery;
```

TIA.

Comment: Compile a local definition and ask the debugger what the type is.  Should end up being some implementation of the interface `IEnumerable<Something>` where `Something` is the type `tab1` gets.

Comment: It depends on the type of `Table`.

Comment: I´m trying to do that to that, to make subsequent filtering :
    myQuery = myQuery.Where(x => x.someField == someChoice);

And declared this way :
    private IQueryable<MyEntity> myQuery;

But i´m receiving the error : "myQuery" conflicts with the declaration of myNameSpace.myEntity.myQuery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `IQueryable<TableEntity>`, where `TableEntity` is the type of the objects in your `Table` `DbSet`.

It may also be an `IEnumerable<TableEntity>`, depending on whether you run your query against a database or some in-memory collection.

You can also see which type to use by hovering your mouse over `myQuery`.

Comment: In fact "myQuery" is much more complex than I put in my question. I´m making a join between 10 tables. So, in this case, what should be the TableEntity used if I´m using a lot of tables ?

Comment: It should be whatever type you use in your `select` clause. If you use an anonymous type, you have 2 choices: either use a named type instead of the anonymous type, or use `dynamic`. Using `dynamic` is not type-safe.

Answer (score 4):

The sneaky way to do this is to make it:

```
this.myQuery = ...
```

then position the caret at the `myQuery` (which will have a red squiggly, indicating a problem), and press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd>, and select the IDE's offer to generate a field:

[image]

This generates a field of the correct type:

[image]

Now just move the query itself into where-ever you need it (presumably a constructor), after `MyTable` has been set.

Comment: classy one... I like the answer.. :)

Answer (score 1):

If you hover your mouse over the `var` keyword it will tell you what type it is.

You can then use that to define a member for the class to hold the result.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `var` keyword and obtain the type and then declare the variable of that type.

Or, if from some reason you do not want to do it that way, you could use a [`dynamic`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd264741.aspx) type, but I would advise against that.

The best solution would be to let the compiler infer the type with the `var` keyword and then use that type explicitly as the class member (the "global variable" as you referred to it).

Answer (score 0):

LINQ queries return some kind of IEnumerable so I believe it will be

```
private IEnumerable<TypeOfObjectInYourCollection> myQuery;
```

Comment: Not necessarily. It might need to be `IQueryable` instead.

Answer (score 0):

The type will be an `IQueryable` of type `tab1`.

Assuming you eventually call `ToList()` to run the query, you'll end up with a `List<tab1>`. So you can declare your global variable as that type.

I'm assuming `tab1` is an object that's available for you to have a list of.

```
List<tab1> result = new List<tab1>();

protected void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var myQuery = from tab1 in Table
                  where myConditions
                  select tab1;

    myQuery.Where(x => x.someField == someChoice);

    result = myQuery.ToList();
}
```

Comment: You don't need to do ToList - IQueryable is a child of IEnumerable.

Comment: Doing ToList will force execution at that point, same as iterating the collection.  It's another topic, but since it's going into a global variable it's a better idea to make the variable a less-derived type (IEnumerable), and to delay execution till needed.

Answer (score 0):

Try `EnumerableRowCollection`:

```
 private EnumerableRowCollection query
```